# Reading and modifying data from a csv in chunks and writing by appending to a csv file is very slow in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, chunks

I am very new to python and pandas and really need help with speeding-up my code.

I am trying to map a certain X,Y coordinate read from an input.csv file to a list of bounding boxes in another mapper.csv file and output only the rows from input.csv and mapper.csv where the X,Y from input.csv is completely contained within a bounding box from mapper.csv (between the min and max).

I tried to use a nested for loop to loop over the input.csv and mapper.csv files.

I used another 3rd for loop for reading the data from the input.csv in chunks, as the number of lines in input.csv are ~1M.

The code is very slow. Takes more than a minute to execute 50rows, even though I clean up the lists after each iteration.

I didn't even bother trying the entire 1M. How can I speed this up? Please help!

Here is what I used:

```
#Read an input csv and a mapper csv files
req_cols = ['Pointer','X', 'Y']
file = 'input.csv'
chunksize = 10000
B = pd.read_csv('mapper.csv',header=0)
map = []
result = []
outfile = 'output.csv'


for chunk in pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=chunksize,usecols=req_cols):
    map = []
    result = []
    for index, row in chunk.iterrows():
        for mapindex, maprow in B.iterrows():
            if float(row["X"]) > maprow["Min_X"] and float(row["Y"]) > maprow["Min_Y"] and float(row["X"]) < maprow["Max_X"] and float(row["Y"]) < maprow["Max_Y"]:

                map.append(maprow)
                result.append(row)
                break

    df_final_chunk = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(result).reset_index(drop=True), pd.DataFrame(map).reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)  
    df_final_chunk.to_csv(outfile, mode='a', header = False)

input.csv=Pointer, X, Y  
     Jh,   23.4,    25.7    
     Ma,   17.3,    18.1    
     Ke,   27.1,    29.4      
     He,   36.2,    38.9
     Fe,   29.4,    29.8
     Tn,   38.1,    39.5          
mapper.csv=Mapper, Min_X, Min_Y, Max_X, Max_Y
     M1,   22.4,    22.7,    40.2,    45.6
     M2,   17.8,    18.9,    29.4,    29.8
     M3,   27.1,    29.4,    38.1,    39.5
```

Comment: Load the full 1M records and filter after with vectorized operations. It will be *much* faster than trying to break the file in blocks and iterating over the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks ApplePie. I am trying to implement numpy vectorization now, although how do I deal with the first column being string in both the input.csv and mapper.csv files? I do want to retain those strings in my output.